# Dúvida código de Js para troca de div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Tenho um site em Wordpress e estou tento dificuldades na seguinte função,
eu criei um pequeno script, que ao clicar em um botão, ele deve substituir uma div por outra, para trocar conteúdo sem recarregar a página, até então tudo bem, funcionou corretamente, mas o grande problema é que tenho muitos botões e muitos conteúdos para exibir e eles precisam estar no mesmo lugar, por exemplo:
Tenho 3 botões, cada um deles tem a sua respectiva lista.
Dentro de cada lista, vão haver diversos itens que terão seus respectivos conteúdos.
Digamos que o cliente clica no primeiro botão, a lista aparece e ele clica em um dos itens da lista, o conteúdo aparece.
Clica no segundo botão, troca a lista e ele clica em um dos itens, o conteúdo muda.

Sou um pouco leigo em Js, e estou tendo dificuldades de fazer essa transição sem ter que recarregar a página, desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Ex imagem do menu:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os botões de cima (cardiacas, abdominais, faciais) é um dos menus, todos feitos em botões, clicando em cada um deles, o container que vai abaixo seria substituído pelo seu respectivo.
Como podem ver ao lado, existe outro menu (Reposição LCD, Reposição Touch, Montagem), clicando em cada item desse o conteúdo ao lado direito teria que mudar.

Vou deixar o código que eu tentei executar, é um código de testes.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('botaocardiacas').onclick = function(){         document.getElementById('menu-cardiacas').innerHTML = document.getElementById('menu-abdominais').innerHTML; } });
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('clique3').onclick = function(){         document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = document.getElementById('conteudo2').innerHTML; } });
```

```css
#teste, #clique1, #clique2 {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

#botaocardiacas, #botaoabdominais, #botaofaciais {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

#menu-cardiacas, #menu-abdominais {
  display:block;
  margin-top:50px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cardiacas">
<button type="button" id="botaocardiacas">cardiacas</button>
</div>

<div id="abdominais">
<button type="button" id="botaoabdominais">abdominais</button>
</div>

<div id="faciais">
<button type="button" id="botaofaciais">faciais</button>
</div>

<div id="menu-cardiacas" class="card">
<div class="teste">
<button type="button" id="clique1">reposição</button>
<button type="button" id="clique2">reposição touch</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="menu-abdominais" style="visibility:hidden;">
<div class="teste">
<button type="button" id="clique3">botao</button>
<button type="button" id="clique4">reposição botao</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="menu-faciais" style="visibility:hidden;">
<div class="teste">
<button type="button" id="clique5">tela</button>
<button type="button" id="clique6">reposição tela</button>
</div>
</div>

<div id="conteudo">
teste, teste
</div>

<div id="conteudo2" style="visibility:hidden;">
teste, teste, teste
</div>
```

Comment: De onde vem o conteúdo dos respectivos botões?

Comment: o conteúdo dos botoes estariam dentro de divs na mesma página, com o atributo hiden, aceito sugestões de maneiras melhores também!

Comment: Acho que você se beneficiaria em um framework como o Vue.js...

Comment: eu estou usando o bootstrap, mas a função dele não está funcionando

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia fazer isso simplesmente colocando as duas divs, uma delas com display: none, no mesmo lugar e cada vez que clica da um display: block em uma e display: none na outra com js, pode criar classes css pra isso também.